# How can I get event listeners from my View Class to refer to methods in Controller Class when View is injected inside the controller?

Tags: javascript, class

I can't work out how to make the event listeners in the view refer to the methods in the Controller. I want to have all my listeners assigned in the view, but is this the way to do it in the constructor?

How can I bind the listeners to the methods in the controller?

```js
class Model {
  constructor(test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
}

class View {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    element.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
    element.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor(penguinView, penguinModel) {
    this.penguinView = penguinView;
    this.penguinModel = penguinModel;
  }

  dragEnter(e) {
    console.log('enter');
  }

  drop(e) {
    console.log('drop');
  }
}

function ready() {
  const penguinModel = new Model();

  const targetElement = document.getElementById('listOfPenguins');
  const penguinView = new View(targetElement);

  const controller = new Controller(penguinView, penguinModel);

  function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  window.addEventListener('dragleave', preventDefault, false);
  window.addEventListener('dragover', preventDefault, false);
  window.addEventListener('drop', preventDefault, false);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="listOfPenguins" class="list-of-penguins"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, developers use to follow an event driven architecture where you can trigger events and attach listeners.

Let's write a base `EventEmitter` class:

```
class EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this._events = {};
  }

  trigger(eventName, eventData) {
    var handlers = this._events[eventName];
    if (handlers) {
      handlers.forEach(handler => handler.call(this, eventData));
    }
    return this;
  }

  on(eventName, eventHandler) {
    this._events[eventName] = this._events[eventName] || [];
    this._events[eventName].push(eventHandler);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Extend `View` from `EventEmitter`:

```
class View extends EventEmitter{
  constructor(element) {
    super();
    this.element = element;

    element.addEventListener('dragenter', (evt) => this.trigger('dragenter', evt), false);
    element.addEventListener('drop', (evt) => this.trigger('drop', evt), false);
  }
}
```

Let `Controller` bind events on `View` instance:

```
class Controller {
  constructor(penguinView, penguinModel) {
    this.penguinView = penguinView;
    this.penguinModel = penguinModel;

    this.penguinView
      .on('dragenter', this.dragEnter)
      .on('drop', this.drop);
  }

  dragEnter(e) {
    console.log('enter');
  }

  drop(e) {
    console.log('drop');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this working but have hit a major stumbling block. I can't seem to call a function in `penguinView` in the `Controller` class. If I have a method in View called `hello()` and in `Controller` a method that says `this.penguinView.hello();` it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think in this direction

```
class View {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    dragEnterInit(fn) {
        element.addEventListener('dragenter', fn, false);
    }

    dropInit(fn) {
        element.addEventListener('drop', fn, false);
    }
}

class Controller {
    constructor(penguinView, penguinModel) {
        this.penguinView = penguinView;
        this.penguinModel = penguinModel;

        this.penguinView.dragEnterInit(this.dragEnter.bind(this));
        this.penguinView.dropInit(this.drop.bind(this));
    }

    dragEnter(e) {
        console.log('enter');
    }

    drop(e) {
        console.log('drop');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was just a bit too verbose, I decided to add the event emitter as suggested above.